# F2FS feature-list

Tags: filesystems, f2fs

In the man page of mkfs.f2fs, I see the option:

> -O feature-list Specify a feature list in order f2fs filesystem will supports. e.g "encrypt" and so on

I'd like to know how can I get the full list of the optional features of f2fs and whether it is possible to modify existing file system and enable some features without data loss.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/f2fs.txt

Comment: Is there a tool like tune2fs that can modify the features of an existing fs (f2fs) without data loss?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jaegeuk/f2fs-tools.git/tree/mkfs/f2fs_format_main.c, the definition of parse_feature is taken from the file `include/f2fs_fs.h`. This function uses a table with 10 feature names (not all make sense for normal users!): https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jaegeuk/f2fs-tools.git/tree/include/f2fs_fs.h#n1361:

`encrypt`
`extra_attr`
`project_quota`
`inode_checksum`
`flexible_inline_xattr`
`quota`
`inode_crtime`
`lost_found`
`verity`
`sb_checksum`

Comment: `casefold` and `compression` have been added.

Answer (score 1):

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jaegeuk/f2fs-tools.git/tree/mkfs/f2fs_format_main.c?h=experimental#n70

Only *encrypt* at the moment it seems.

Comment: Why have you added the "experimental" part in your URL?

Comment: what about `compress`?